# How to trigger day/week event from outside full calendar

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

Can we make events trigger/click of day/week/next/preview outside the **full calendar**?

Comment: Provide a snippet, link to any required libraries and desribe your desired outcome more specifically.

Comment: Your wording is too brief and unclear to understand what you really mean. If you want some detailed help, you'll need to put a lot more effort into your question. But on a basic level, you can handle https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/ which fires whenever someone clicks on an event. Within that, you can do anything you like. There's also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/ which fires whenever the date or the view is changed (so on click of the next/prev buttons, or any of the view buttons, or calls to the equivalent FC methods which cause those events).

Comment: http://codepen.io/miqureshi/pen/jmzNwB

Comment: http://codepen.io/miqureshi/pen/jmzNwB

This pen has a code snippet I put my custom links over full calendar I want these links to work as full calendar day/week working.

Comment: they'd have to fire the changeView method with the appropriate parameters, then. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/changeView/ . Or you could just re-style the existing buttons using CSS to look like yours.

Comment: @ADyson yes buttons can be re-styled but in my UI buttons placement are on heading section I tried to re positioned them but in full calendar defined overflow:hidden.

Comment: I didn't suggest re-positioning your buttons, I suggested re-styling fullCalendar's to look like yours, and then removing yours. If you don't want to move them, then you need to hook into the fullCalendar methods as I described, and then probably remove the fullCalendar ones, so it's not duplicated. Up to you.

Comment: Yes you didn`t suggest re-positioning I told I tried actually this, anyway I am trying what you suggest earlier thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do it by using "**ChangeView**" within the fullcalendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the link [Fullcalendar External/Draggable Events Highlight Effect and ChangeView fullcalendar](http://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/XRjzrv)

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-20">
    <div class="week">WEEK</div>
    <div class="day">DAY</div>
    <div id='exampleCalendar'></div>
</div>


$('.week').click(function() {
    $('#exampleCalendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaWeek');
});

$('.day').click(function() {
    $('#exampleCalendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaDay');
});
```